# Unity override Android Application onCreate Method

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I need to call a Java code (initialize an Android library) in onCreate() of Application class in my Unity cross-platform project.

Can someone explain how to achieve this?

Comment: why not use Awake instead of onCreate?

Comment: @Bizhan I need instance of Application class to be passed as argument within onCreate method of Application class. Is that possible through Awake method?

Comment: You can actually use some C# code to get your activity, get application context from it and initialise the SDK you want. I think this might work